# put two named instances in MEF

Tags: .net, mef

In Unity I would do something like this:

```
Container.RegisterType<MyClass>("MyNamedInstance", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Then I could put multiple instances of the same class in.

How can I do this in MEF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like named exports were added in the latest preview release ([MEF 2 Preview 3](http://mef.codeplex.com/releases/view/61730)) as part of [MEF's Convention Model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hammett/archive/2011/03/08/mef-s-convention-model.aspx) (see the "explicit wiring" section).

However, this is not yet available in .NET 4. Also, the APIs in the preview releases are subject to change.

For now, you could create two exports for the same class with different contracts by adding the name to the export's contract:

```
public class MyClass
{
}

public class MyClassExporter
{

   [Export("Name1", typeof(MyClass))]
   public MyClass Name1
   {
       get
       {
           return new MyClass();
       }
   }

   [Export("Name2", typeof(MyClass))]
   public MyClass Name2
   {
       get
       {
           return new MyClass();
       }
   }
}
```

and then you could use the same contract for imports:

```
[Export(typeof(IFoo))]
public class Foo : IFoo
{
   [ImportingConstructor]
   public Foo([Import("Name2", typeof(MyClass))] MyClass myClass)
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

Instead of using a `MyClassExporter` with property exports you could also put the export attributes on derived classes, which is perhaps easier to understand but doesn't work on [sealed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) classes:

```
[Export("Name1", typeof(MyClass)]
public class MyClass1 : MyClass
{
}

[Export("Name2", typeof(MyClass)]
public class MyClass2 : MyClass
{
}
```

Comment: ExportAttribute is set to AllowMultiple = true. I'm pretty sure that means you can tag a single class with multiple named exports :)

Comment: @myermian: having multiple exports on the same class doesn't really result in "named instances", as it is not possible to create two separate singletons that way. See also my comment on your answer.

Comment: This will really return a singleton?  It seems to new up the class each time?

Comment: @zachary: Yes, the property getter is invoked only once by MEF for a given export (except if the importer explicitly requires `CreationPolicy.NonShared` on the import). You can easily verify this by putting a breakpoint in the getter.

Answer (score 1):

[ExportAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.exportattribute.aspx)

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class|AttributeTargets.Method|AttributeTargets.Property|AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = true, 
    Inherited = false)]
public class ExportAttribute : Attribute
```

It is marked for AllowMultiple = true... which means you can do the following:

```
[Export("MyClass1")]
[Export("MyClass2")]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)] //Otherwise they'll point to the same reference.
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: The reason I didn't suggest this in my own answer is because this doesn't allow you to create two singletons. **Each importer of "MyClass1" will get a a new object**, which is not really what a you intend when you want a "named instance".

Comment: @Wim, Yes, I agree. You won't get 2 singletons. But, didn't the author state he wants "multiple instances of the same class", which to me sounds like he wants non-singletons. If his intention was to have 2 singletons, then yes, you're solution is correct.